# Checklist of android resources/assets required before starting development

Tags: android, android-resources, android-icons

I am going to develop an android app, but unlike my previous apps, this time I have to tell someone what graphics and assets I require even before starting the development. The designer has designed all the screens, and now looking at those screens I have to tell him what resources(in what sizes and densities), fonts, icons etc I require.

Does there exist a checklist, which cleanly lists all the required graphics(for different sizes and densities), and assets including those graphics which are required only at the time of app publishing.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work in a company where I have to tell designers as well. So despite any hard mapped check list, it always helps if you make the designer understand a bit on how the Android works.

Don't forget that color codes, XML drawables (borders, gradients) and 9-patch are way more efficient than static PNGs.

Then I make him do everything just for the Galaxy Nexus on XHDPI and only after the whole development is complete that I ask for the other resized assets (because assets tend to change throughout the project and then I don't have to be updating all of them).

Despite what is on the mock-ups is just a few more assets:

- launcher icon,
- high-res launcher (512 x 512)
- promotional graphs (180w x 120h)
- feature graphic (1024 x 500)

the other you'll use registering on Google Play is the screen shots which you can get from the real app, after it's complete.

Comment: yes you are right. But designers cannot understand tangible things, they are just f****ng creative. Also some rigid bosses make the thing even worse.

Comment: LOL... I really understand your point, but it's not a perfect world, uh.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers totally answers this question but I just wanted to add something to Budius. I know I am not suppose to reply to other answers but as a Designer I think I should point something out.

Budius said "make him do everything just for the Galaxy Nexus on XHDPI". I would suggest having him make everything on MDPI as MDPI is the current baseline. Reasoning behind this is that in no matter what program used, ex: Photoshop, it is much more cleaner to scale up than to scale down. Scaling down sometimes results in weird artefacts and require adjustments where as scaling up usually results in a perfect scale.